# How to get IP of someone downloading files

Tags: apex, files, developer

I'm writing a class that implements Sfc.ContentDownloadHandlerFactory and I want to know on each download attempt, the IP of the person who downloaded the file.

I'm aware of UserInfo.getUserId() but I want to know also the IP for public links shared by my organization, when a user doesnt have to be logged on.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to work with this?:

```
String ip = Auth.SessionManagement.getCurrentSession().get('SourceIp');
```

This will get the IP of the current session. Running this from a Execute Anonymous will give you the your IP address.

What if you try this?:

```
string ReturnIpValue = '';

ReturnIpValue = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('True-Client-IP');
```

I have not code to test this to help you more, but try the last one on your Visualforce page.

Is  that Visualforce public and exposed to the web?
Are you using Sites for this page?

Comment: When i try to download from a public link without being logged in, and im trying to access Auth.SessionManagement.getCurrentSession() in my class - The download will fail and im redirected to a "Unable to Process Request" page

Answer (score 1):

You could get the Ip addresses of all the user who downloaded the file just by implementing the simple code.

```
String ipAddress = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('X-Salesforce-SIP');
```

'True-Client-IP' – when the request is coming via the caching integration.
'X-Salesforce-SIP' – when the request is not via caching integration (sandbox, 
 developer edition orgs) or via the secure url.
For Example  :

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" controller="IpAddClass">
<h1>IP Address</h1>
<apex:form><apex:commandButton action="{!getIpAddress}" value="get Ip Address"/> 
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Its controller -

```
public class IpAddClass {
public pageReference getIpAddress(){
        String ipAddress = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('X- 
Salesforce-SIP');
        System.debug('ip address '+ipAddress);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: inside my class, when im trying to access Auth.SessionManagement.getCurrentSession() i just get null...

Comment: @user62930 try the above one